# Using JEST with react-native-elements - mockModal is not a function

Tags: react-native, jestjs, react-native-elements

Is it possible to use jest in `react-native` projects, which use components from `react-native-elements`?

The example jest file [https://github.com/vanGalilea/react-native-testing/blob/master/**tests**/Login.test.tsx](https://github.com/vanGalilea/react-native-testing/blob/master/__tests__/Login.test.tsx) works fine as it is. As soon as I change the `<Text>` component from the `react-native` version to the `react-native-elements` version, I get the following error message.

```
  ● Test suite failed to run

    Jest encountered an unexpected token
    Jest failed to parse a file. This happens e.g. when your code or its dependencies use non-standard JavaScript syntax, or when Jest is not configured to support such syntax.
    Out of the box Jest supports Babel, which will be used to transform your files into valid JS based on your Babel configuration.
    By default "node_modules" folder is ignored by transformers.
    Here's what you can do:
....
....
    Details:
    C:\react\testingLibrary\node_modules\react-native-elements\dist\index.js:6
    import Button from './buttons/Button';
    ^^^^^^

    SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
```

I added the following line to the `jest.config.js` file.

```js
transformIgnorePatterns: ['node_modules/(?!(jest-)?@react-native|react-native|react-native-elements/*)',],
```

This got rid of the error above. However, now, I am getting the following error message.

```
  ● Test suite failed to run

    TypeError: mockModal is not a function

      at node_modules/react-native/jest/setup.js:116:12
      at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/react-native/jest/mockModal.js:16:15)
      at node_modules/react-native/jest/setup.js:115:28
```

Environment:

1. react-native: 0.67.0
2. react-native-elements: 3.4.2
3. @testing-library/jest-native: 4.0.4
4. @testing-library/react-native: 9.0.0
5. jest: 27.4.7
6. metro-react-native-babel-preset: 0.66.2
7. react-test-renderer: 17.0.2
8. @babel/core: 7.16.7
9. @babel/runtime: 7.16.7
10. babel-jest: 27.4.6

Comment: I just upgraded from 0.66.4 to 0.67.1 and had tests that were using react-native-elements and they were passing before the upgrade. I now see the same error as you, so it would seem to be specifically with 0.67.x and not react-native in general. Hopefully, someone has an answer!

Comment: Looks like this is also an issue with Modal imported from react-native itself: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/32939

Answer (score 3):

Try using this mock

```
import .....

jest.mock('@rneui/themed', ()=>({
  Button: jest.fn()
}));

describe( ... )
```

Answer (score 1):

```
● Test suite failed to run

    TypeError: mockModal is not a function

      at node_modules/react-native/jest/setup.js:116:12
```

Update to react-native version 0.67.2 to fix mockModal issue. Here is the update from react-native:
https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/main/CHANGELOG.md#fixed

Issue:
https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/32939

Answer (score 0):

A temporary workaround is to downgrade react-native to `0.66.4`. This seems to fix the problem.

**Update 2022-01-21:**

The `react-native-elements` development team acknowledged the problem. Moreover, they have already fixed it in the beta version `4.0.0-beta.0`. Check the following issue for the latest updates on this bug.
https://github.com/react-native-elements/react-native-elements/issues/3304